# SC16IS740IPW alternative - want DIP housing

Tags: integrated-circuit, infrared, component-selection

I am working on [Infrared receiver based on Vishay's TFBS4711](https://www.vishay.com/ir-transceivers/list/product-82633/) and I've added [SC16IS740 Single UART with I2C-bus/SPI interface](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf) for simplyfing communication with `Vishay's IR transciever`. Now, I am working on this subproject in [Altium](https://www.altium.com/), and therefore I've [varianted](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.1/display/ADES/((Design+Variants))_AD) the PCB to *through-hole* and *smd* variant (for the sake of learning `Altium` and testing purposes of PCB once it is finished - *through-hole* variant will be used) and I cannot find alternative to [SC16IS740](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf), which resides in [DIP/DIL housing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package). I've been searching on internet for about a week, without results, can someone help me.

P.S.: I am aware this is rather stupid question on the verge of downvoting, but I am getting simply desperate!

Comment: If the actual question is about finding an alternative for the SC16IS740, you should remove all the other clutter to improve your chances for getting a response.

Comment: What Rev1.0 said. You could also use a breakout board for the TSSOP variant and use that as a fake DIP housing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you haven't actually listed *which* package of SMD SC16IS740 you have chosen, it doesn't really matter so much as there is no DIP packaged version.

Instead, flex your Altium skills further and make a daughterboard "breakout board" PCB. Just replace what would be DIP pegs with header pins to the correct pitch.

[image]